# Custom google sheets function returning "Illegally formed XML syntax. (Last line) - PHP script

Tags: php, xml, google-sheets-api

I have been trying to implement this function in google sheets, however it keeps returning "Illegally formed xml syntax" in line 93,the very last line "?>". I have attached the code without my personal information.

I am pasting this code in the code editor of google sheets by coding to tools --> Script editor, does anyone know what I need to change?

If anyone could help me figure out where I am going wrong implementing this custom function code into google sheets it would be much appreciated!

Code Starts: (Sorry I couldn't figure out how to input it correctly)

```
<?php


// Region code and Product ASIN
$response = getAmazonPrice("com", "B00KQPGRRE");

function getAmazonPrice($region, $asin) {

$xml = aws_signed_request($region, array(
    "Operation" => "ItemLookup",
    "ItemId" => $asin,
    "IncludeReviewsSummary" => False,
    "ResponseGroup" => "Medium,OfferSummary",
));

$item = $xml->Items->Item;
$title = htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->Title);
$url = htmlentities((string) $item->DetailPageURL);
$image = htmlentities((string) $item->MediumImage->URL);
$price = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->Amount);
$code = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->CurrencyCode);
$qty = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->TotalNew);

if ($qty !== "0") {
    $response = array(
        "code" => $code,
        "price" => number_format((float) ($price / 100), 2, '.', ''),
        "image" => $image,
        "url" => $url,
        "title" => $title
    );
}

return $response;
}

function getPage($url) {

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $html;
}

function aws_signed_request($region, $params) {

$public_key = "PUBLIC_KEY";
$private_key = "PRIVATE_KEY";

$method = "GET";
$host = "ecs.amazonaws." . $region;
$host = "webservices.amazon." . $region;
$uri = "/onca/xml";

$params["Service"] = "AWSECommerceService";
$params["AssociateTag"] = "affiliate-20"; // Put your Affiliate Code here
$params["AWSAccessKeyId"] = $public_key;
$params["Timestamp"] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
$params["Version"] = "2011-08-01";

ksort($params);

$canonicalized_query = array();
foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
    $param = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($param));
    $value = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($value));
    $canonicalized_query[] = $param . "=" . $value;
}

$canonicalized_query = implode("&", $canonicalized_query);

$string_to_sign = $method . "\n" . $host . "\n" . $uri . "\n" . $canonicalized_query;
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, $private_key, True));
$signature = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($signature));

$request = "http://" . $host . $uri . "?" . $canonicalized_query . "&Signature=" . $signature;
$response = getPage($request);

var_dump($response);

$pxml = @simplexml_load_string($response);
if ($pxml === False) {
    return False;// no xml
} else {
    return $pxml;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: You probably don't need the ?> at the end of the script.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply! and for the edit!
I have tried removing the ?> at the end of the script and it returns that the } before it is not the syntax error. I am pasting this code in the code editor of google sheets by coding to tools --> Script editor

Comment: If your script is inside a html then you would need the <? and ?>. But it is run outside by the php interpreter, you don't need it. Did the code work after you removed the ?>

Comment: Wow thanks again or your quick reply! I really appreciate the help. I have removed the ?> at the end and it returned that the "}" is the syntax error in the line before it. I have also tried taking away the "<?php" and the "?>" at the same time and received that line 7 was the syntax error. ""Operation" => "ItemLookup"," that line was the syntax error with both removed

Comment: Did you see the example at https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/php

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing I really appreciate all your help. I still can't get it to work, do you think there's an error inside the code? I have tried removing the last line. Do I need something to replace it? Does it run for you? Thanks again! I am really new to this world and appreciate all the input!

Comment: I did not see the ending ?> in the code sample that they provided. I copied the code they provided pasted it in a editor and verified. They only had the beginning section which is kind of wierd to me.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing Thanks again for your help. Do you think anythings wrong with my code? I have tried removing the "?>" at the end. Can you get my code to save?

Answer (score 0):

Please try serving canonical URLs with `https` instead of using `http`.

As stated in [HTTPS required for active content](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#https_required_for_active_content)

> ["Active" content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content#Mixed_active_content) like scripts, external stylesheets, and **XmlHttpRequests must be loaded over HTTPS, not HTTP**.

Hope that works for you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I changed it to https in the code and it still didn't work. I think that solved another issue with my script though. I have no idea what to do from here, any help is very much appreciated. I am very new to this world